# How to make message notification like Stackoverflow?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Our team want to add the notification function on our website. Now, it's the design stage. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which actual SO notification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up your web browser and go into firebug/chrome inspector/developer tools.  Visit the stack overflow site.  Look on the console at the global variable 'StackExchange'.  It has everything you need for notifications, how votes are added, comments, etc...  It is very well designed and very thought out.  I use it as inspiration constantly.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pretty straightforward task, but if you want to simplify the process, there is a jQuery plugin that does it [here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/jquery_plugin_for_showing_message_box_in_topbar.aspx). There's also a more popup-style plugin called [JNotifyOSD](http://vickychijwani.github.com/jquery-notify-osd/).

Answer (score 1):

The [jnotify](http://www.givainc.com/labs/jnotify_jquery_plugin.htm) plugin will give you what you need to make this happen on the client side. Once you have a mechanism for making your notifications available to the browser, you can just call jnotify to display the notification.